# Utilize the single row function and concatenate when querying a statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

Trying to concatenate a statement trying to get the following results;

```
josh is their name and they earn $x.
```

The statement I wrote and got wrong;

```sql
Select 
    concatenate (lower (ename), 'is their name', 'and they earn' (sal)) as chart 
from emp:
```

Comment: `CONCATENATE` is not a function, I expect you want [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You're also missing a comma after `'and they earn'` and `(sal)` (the parentheses are unnecessary here by the way. This should work: `SELECT CONCAT(LOWER(ename), ' is their name and they earn ', sal) AS chart FROM emp;`. I would however be very wary of doing things like this in SQL, do it in your presentation layer, and simply return data from the database. Your way you lose the ability to do further manipulation (e.g. sort by salary)

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself in your question; the 2 boxes are meant to have different information, not copied text from the first pasted into the second.

Comment: You are also missing spaces between the parts.

Answer (score 1):

While there is concat() function in SQL server, you could simply use + operator to concatenate strings. Also you can use Format() to format values. ie:

```
create table emp (ename varchar(20), sal decimal(20,4));
insert into emp (ename, sal) values 
  ('Josh', 1000),
  ('Mike', 1200),
  ('Ian', 1500);



Select lower (ename) + 
   ' is their name and they earn ' + 
    FORMAT(sal, '$#,#.##') as chart 
from emp;
```

| chart |
| --- |
| josh is their name and they earn $1,000 |
| mike is their name and they earn $1,200 |
| ian is their name and they earn $1,500 |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wu04XtP6)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(LOWER(ename), 'is their name and they earn ', (sal)) as chart 
FROM emp
```